# What is the block height from which RingCT was implemented?

Tags: blockchain, ringct

Can we know the block height from which the ring signatures were implemented. Because i read few blocks which are pre-ring signature blocks where I see there are ring members repeating for a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ring CT was implemented in block #1220516 in January 2017. After September 2017, this feature became mandatory for all transactions on the network.

https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/ringCT.html

It's worth noting that Ring**CT** is an improvement which added the Confidential Transactions part to the transaction format. Ring *signatures* existed before RingCT was implemented.

Comment: can a ring signature have recurring ringmembers offsets? I found few transactions which have same ring members repeating in the same transaction

Comment: When you say "recurring ringmembers offsets" this is ambiguous. Please link to example tx.